# cannot convert type decimal to double

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, web-services

I have a simple web service calling a sql view table through entity framework. I can bring all the columns in string fine but not the column in numeric like UID_NUM(numeric(38,8), null) in SQL. I have AddressALL class to set columns like below and error out at p.UID_NUM in LINQ.

```
public class GISAddressWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
     [WebMethod]
     public AddressALL[] getAddress()
     {
         try
         {
             List<view_COBADDRESS> address = new List<view_COBADDRESS>();
             using (GISAddressEntities database = new GISAddressEntities())
             {
                 return database.view_COBADDRESS
                        .Where(p => p.UNIT_NUM == "103")
                        .Select(p => new AddressALL { UID_NUM = p.UID_NUM, ADD_FULL = p.ADD_FULL, POSTALCITY = p.POSTALCITY, ZIP5 = p.ZIP5}).ToArray();
             }
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
}

public class AddressALL
{
     public double UID_NUM { get; set; }
     public string TLID { get; set; }
     public string ADD_FULL { get; set; }
     public string POSTALCITY { get; set; }
     public string STATE { get; set; }
     public string ZIP5 { get; set; }
     public string IN_OUT { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Why not use (double)p.UID_NUM?

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. It works!

Comment: if you put your comment in answer, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Is there a way to select all instead of listing all columns?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Have a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21634/looping-through-columns-in-entity-framework) site. Or look at a framework like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal has more significant figures than the double, therefore it can be more precise and it also takes up slightly more memory. Because of this difference fou must explicitly program this change of type through (double)p.UID_NUM.

Comment: Is there a way to select all instead of listing all columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
return database.view_COBADDRESS
                        .Where(p => p.UNIT_NUM == "103")
                        .Select(p => new AddressALL { UID_NUM = System.Convert.ToDouble(p.UID_NUM), ADD_FULL = p.ADD_FULL, POSTALCITY = p.POSTALCITY, ZIP5 = p.ZIP5}).ToArray();
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2zyd0fa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: your code makes no programming error however no value returns.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution, instead of

```
.Select(p => new AddressALL
        {
            UID_NUM = p.UID_NUM,
            ADD_FULL = p.ADD_FULL,
            POSTALCITY = p.POSTALCITY,
            ZIP5 = p.ZIP5
        });
```

write

```
.Select(p => new AddressALL
        {
            UID_NUM = Convert.ToDouble(p.UID_NUM),
            ADD_FULL = p.ADD_FULL,
            POSTALCITY = p.POSTALCITY,
            ZIP5 = p.ZIP5
        });
```

In your select statement `.Select(p => new AddressALL{ ... })` you are doing a [projection](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/Linq/Lesson02) that is trying to pick a new object of type `AddressALL` for each `p`, and you are using the object initializer syntax `{...}` to match the properties of your source objects `p` with the properties of your target type `AddressALL`.

Your error message however suggests your `p.UID_NUM` is of type `decimal`, while the `UID_NUM` property on your `AddressALL` is of type `double`. Therefore you have to convert the values to the necessary target type.

Comment: when I omit UID_NUM = Convert.ToDouble(p.UID_NUM), it returns value that I expect but with UID_NUM, it returns nothing but no program error.